# Tabularray inside longtabularray

Tags: tabularray

Some hlines are missing when I use the `long` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[long]{
        colspec={XXX},
        vlines,hlines}
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec={cc},
        vlines,
        hlines}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
\end{tblr}
& B & C \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/227

This bug should has been fixed. Everyone could download and try the latest package file
[package file](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty).

[image]